# replace 'with' with immediate function

Tags: javascript

I'm refactoring some piece of code:

```
with (form.proxy_settings) {
      PutValue("Usage", 1);
      PutValue("Server", 2);
      PutValue("ServerPort", 3);
      PutValue("Login", 3);
}
```

I want to remove `with`. Should I do like that?

```
(function() {
      ps.PutValue("Usage", 1);
      ps.PutValue("Server", 2);
      ps.PutValue("ServerPort", 3);
      ps.PutValue("Login", 3);
}(form.proxy_settings);
```

Or is it better in this particular case to simply add `form.proxy_settings` to where it is required?

Comment: good call for wanting to remove `with`. It certainly has its uses, but it doesn't look like this is one of them.

Comment: @lbstr - I'm just curious, what is a "good" use of the `with` construct?

Comment: @jfriend00 The coolest usage I've seen is in [this video](http://ejohn.org/blog/talk-khan-academy-computer-science/), but most of us aren't working on the kind of stuff John is. I was also reading something about how JavaScript consoles use them to make certain things available as if local, but I can't seem to find it. I've **never** found a need to use `with` in my own code.

Comment: @lbstr - and `strict` mode prohibits the use of `with`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, if you use a function, you need to declare the argument `ps`:

```
(function(ps) {
      ps.PutValue("Usage", 1);
      ps.PutValue("Server", 2);
      ps.PutValue("ServerPort", 3);
      ps.PutValue("Login", 3);
}(form.proxy_settings);
```

But, you don't really need to execute a function.  This will work just as well and is a common javascript design pattern to save both typing and increase performance over using the longer name in each line:

```
var ps = form.proxy_settings;
ps.PutValue("Usage", 1);
ps.PutValue("Server", 2);
ps.PutValue("ServerPort", 3);
ps.PutValue("Login", 3);
```

Comment: So I'd execute an immediate function if I didn't want the variable, in this case `ps`, to be accesible outside the `with commands` block?

Comment: @Maximus - that would be the main difference except that you are presumably already in your own function so nobody outside that function can get to the `ps` variable any way.  And, the function is probably slower to execute.  And using the local variable allows your references that use it to be in multiple places in the function (something that is often needed), not forced into a single block of sequential code.